# NODEJS - SFTP - Handling process output

Tags: node.js, debian, sftp

At the moment I'm trying to use [node-sftp](https://github.com/ajaxorg/node-sftp) in order to provide my nodejs script with the ability to SFTP with a private key.

That module appears to be broken since v 0.6 of node (tty.open is no longer a method).
So i've tried to use a child process and spawn my sftp command.

Now the connection appears to work fine (I checked the ftp servers logs @ /var/log/auth.log)
I can also see some output in the Node window...

```
Permanently added '46.x.x.x' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Connected to 46.x.x.x.
Changing to: /home/deploy/somefolder
```

When I connect directly via the command line using the following command it ends up with a prompt like **sftp>**, which is waiting for my FTP commands

```
sftp -o Port=22 -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o IdentityFile=private_key -o UserKnownHostsFile=/v/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o BatchMode=yes deploy@46.x.x.x:/home/deploy/somefolder
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on where I might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its hard to say without a little more detail, but I would take a look at:
https://github.com/chjj/pty.js/

This will emulate a tty device that you can read and write to.

If you can provide some additional code you have tried, we may be able to point you in a better direction.

You could also try cloning the node-sftp module from: https://github.com/ajaxorg/node-sftp.git and using the library directly instead of from npm, it looks like the latest version in github has support for node versions newer that 0.6

Comment: The version of node-sftp that I got via NPM wasn't working well, I think the one from github contains the pty thing you mentioned and so SFTP connections worked fine. ty anyway